# Boys get a box that supposedly helps with mental powers, by playing the song "Jingle Bells"

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember as a young adult reading a story where boys get a box that supposedly helps with mental powers, by playing the song "Jingle Bells" when their minds reach a state referred to as "state 16," which they finally do by accident after giving up and laughing about their attempt. I seem to remember the ending being something to do with bikers and chili (green dragon chili)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a short story or a novel? Also, in roughly which year or decade did you read it, and when do you think it might've been published? And if it was a short story, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Answer (score 17):

This is almost certainly *Alan Mendelsohn, the Boy from Mars* by Daniel M. Pinkwater.  It has it all: bikers (a gang of Tibetan adepts), chili (from the Bermuda Triangle Chili Parlor), "Jingle Bells" (played by the Klugarsh Mind Control Omega Meter!) and mental power.  (An excellent book, too, BTW.)

Comment: I absolutely love Pinkwater's works!  _Yobgorgle_, _Lizard Music_, _The Hoboken Chicken Emergency_, _Fat Men From Outer Space_...  all great rides!  